# Projection on sum of Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

If we have projections $P$ and $Q$ on Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$, respectively. It is easy to see that the operator matrix 
$$ S=\begin{bmatrix} P & 0 \\ 0 & Q \end{bmatrix} $$ determines a projection on $X\oplus Y$ such that $R(S)= R(P) \oplus R(Q)$ and $N(S)=N(P)\oplus N(Q)$. My question is this. If I have a projection $S$ on $X\oplus Y$, what would be the proper representation of this projection in the form of a $2\times 2$ operator matrix ? Would it be a diagonal operator matrix ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'representation of [the] projection" and what do you mean by "diagonal operator matrix"? If I have $P$ and $Q$ projections on $X$ and $Y$ respectively then some $S$ on $X\oplus Y$ defined as $S(x+y) = Px+Qy$ for all $x\in X$ and $y \in Y$ is a projection as $S^2 = S$. I'm not sure that general Banach space operators always admit matrix representations, so you might have to restrict the hypothesis to Hilbert space operators instead.

Comment: Well, in this case every bounded linear operator $B: X\oplus Y \rightarrow X \oplus Y $ can be represented as $$ B= \begin{bmatrix} B_1 & B_2 \\ B_3 & B_4 \end{bmatrix} : \begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \end{bmatrix} $$. So my question is, if we have a projection $S : X \oplus Y \rightarrow X \oplus Y$, must it's matrix representation be diagonal in the sense that $$ S = \begin{bmatrix} S_1 & 0 \\ 0 & S_2 \end{bmatrix} ?$$

Comment: In that case no, since you can always find a basis in which the "matrix" is not diagonal, see gerw's answer.

Answer (score 0):

No. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be a vector of norm $1$, but not aligned with the coordinate axes. Then, $x \, x^\top$ is a projection which is not block-diagonal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although a counter example in infitinite dimensional Banach spaces would be more interesting ( since I was already familiar with counterexamples such as this one).

Comment: Then take any infinite dimensional Hilbert space $H$ and consider the projection $\mathbb{R}^2 \times H \ni (y,h) \mapsto (x\,x^\top y , h)$ on the space $\mathbb{R} \times (\mathbb{R} \times H)$.

Comment: Yes, and it can be represented as an operator matrix of the form  $$ \begin{bmatrix} xx^\bot & 0 \\ 0 & I_H \end{bmatrix}: \begin{bmatrix} \mathbb{R}^2 \\ H \end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} \mathbb{R}^2 \\ H \end{bmatrix}.  $$

Comment: Yes, this works if you factor the space like $(\mathbb{R}^2) \times (H)$, but not if you factor it like $\mathbb{R} \times (\mathbb{R} \times H)$, i.e. $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $Y = \mathbb{R} \times H$.

Comment: My question was about spaces was about operators on sums of spaces themselves without different factorisations.